# RequireJS: always use plugin when specific extension are loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is there a way to configure RequireJS to always use a specific plugin, when a certain extension has been found?

I would like to avoid to manually call the plugin like `require('es6!myModule')`

Some sort of a-la WebPack config is what I'm looking for, but I haven't had much luck in the docs nor the web

```
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is very limited the support it provides for what you are trying to do. It does not have any kind of pattern matching capabilities in the general sense of the word "pattern matching". In particular, there's no way to tell RequireJS to match files with a specific extension. If you must stick with RequireJS, and the set of modules that must get the plugin is a fixed set known when you are building your application, you could generate a map like this:

```
map: {
  "*": {
    foo: "plugin!foo",
    bar: "plugin!bar",
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `"*"` is not actually a glob or any kind of sophisticated pattern matching. It is more like an encoded keyword that means "any module".

I have an application written in TypeScript that I must be able to run through RequireJS and be able to process through Webpack. I have a few modules that are essentially JSON data. The TypeScript compiler does not like to see plugin names in module imports. So to get everything to work smoothly I keep plugin names out of the TypeScript code code and I use a `map` like the above to have RequireJS use the `json` plugin for the modules that need it. I manage the map manually because it is only a few files.

---

SystemJS supports loading AMD modules and has much more sophisticated configuration facilities than RequireJS. What RequireJS calls a "plugin" is called a "loader" in SystemJS. You can use the `meta` option to associated a loader with a pattern of files:

```
{
  baseURL: "lib/",
  paths: {
    // ...
  },
  meta: {
    "something/*.js": {
      loader: "some-loader",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, and I'm currently debating whether I can add that to the repo: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1716